# Importing file contents into a struct in C

Tags: c, file, struct, linked-list

This is a simple function I am making in order to learn how to copy data from files into structs.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define FILENAME "studentlist.txt"

struct node {
    char *name[20];
    int age;
    struct node *next;
};

typedef struct node Node;

int main(){

    Node *p,*head = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    Node **listPtr;
    *listPtr = head;
    p = head;
    int num;

    FILE *students;
    if ((students = fopen(FILENAME,"r")) == NULL)
            printf("Error: Cant open file\n");
    else
    {
            num = fscanf("%i", &num);
            int i = 0;
            for (i = 0; i <= num; i++){
                    fscanf(students,"%s %i", p->name, p->age);
                    p = p->next;
                    p = malloc(sizeof(Node));
                    }

return 0;
}
```

The errors I am getting are related to the fscanf function. I am also getting

```
 expected 'struct FILE * __restrict__' but argument is of type 'char *'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: and which line is telling you that? Nevermind, I figured it out. Look below.

Answer (score 2):

You just forgot the `FILE*` in the line.

```
num = fscanf("%i", &num );
```

That should be

```
num = fscanf( students, "%i", &num );
```

You should read the whole error. It tells you which line and possibly the character that is giving you an issue. They tell you the problem, which is 90% of solving it.

Answer (score 1):

The signature of the standard library function `fscanf` is

```
int fscanf(FILE *stream, const char *format, ...);
```

Therefore, the following statement is wrong -

```
num = fscanf("%i", &num);
```

The format string literal `"%i"` evaluates to a pointer to its first element, which is of type `char *`. However, `fscanf` expects the first argument of type `FILE *`. This explains the error statement. Replace this line with -

```
num = fscanf(students, "%i", &num);
```

Comment: +1 for explaining the error. I was working on adding that to my answer but you beat me.